# Pytorch: Reshape 1d to 2d target

Tags: pytorch

Apologies if this has been answered already but I couldn't find it.

I have a binary classification problem which I have been using `CrossEntropyLoss` for which expects the following input and target tensor dimensions:

[image: CrossEntropyLoss dimension input requirements]

I have switched to using `BCEWithLogitsLoss` with pre-calculated class weights to address a label imbalance problem. The issue is `BCEWithLogitsLoss` expects the following dimensions:

[image: BCEWithLogitsLoss dimension input requirements]

How would I go about shaping my 1D tensor, ie. `tensor([[0, 0, 0,  ..., 1, 0, 0]])` to the shape of my inputs which is `(No. of X samples, 2)`? I have tried `.unsqueeze(1)` but this gives me `(#X, 1)`. To clarify, my input shape in the prior problem was `[32,2]` with target shape `[32]` as per above documentation and I am looking for `[32,2]` for both input and target dims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring the problem out, didn't realise there was built-in one-hot encoding functionality in Pytorch.

I used the line `torch.nn.functional.one_hot(targets)` which reshaped my target variable to `torch.Size([32, 2])`.